# Angular Material Table Row - How can i right click an open in a new tab

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material table to generate a table populated by my server.

https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

For each row a user can click to open a detailed version which goes to a new page.

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="show(row)"></mat-row>
```

--

```
show(job) {
    this.router.navigate(['reports/', job.job_id]);
}
```

However an end user has rightly noted that in the angular material table you cannot right click and "open in new tab" there is no option for this.

Im assuming because mat-row does not work like an anchor tag. is there someway i can make it work like this.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `mat-menu` and add `[hasBackdrop]=false` property and also add a method that will get triggered when clicked on a button inside the menu

```
 openSite(siteUrl) {
    window.open(siteUrl, "Hello");
  }
```

Please find the reference [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-new-tab?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it that way!

```
show(job) {
  const url = this.router.serializeUrl(
    this.router.createUrlTree([`reports/${job.job_id}`])
  );

  window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```